# passing large number of arguments to struct.pack

Tags: python, struct

I am using struct.pack method which takes variable number of arguments. I want to convert a string to bytes. If a string is short (e.g. 'name') I  can do it like:

```
bytes = struct.pack('4c','n','a','m','e')
```

But what to do when my string is 80 characters long?

I have tried the format string 's', instead of '80c' for struct.pack, but the result is not the same as that of above call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "80s", not just "s". The input is a single string, rather than a series of characters. i.e.

```
bytes = struct.pack('4s','name')
```

Note that if you specify a length greater than that of the input, the output will be null-padded.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't make much sense. Strings are already bytes in python 2.x; So you could just do:

```
my_string = 'I am some big string'
my_bytes = my_string
```

On python 3, strings are unicode objects by default. To get bytes you have to encode the string.

```
my_bytes = my_string.encode('utf-8')
```

If really you want to use `struct.pack`, you'd use `* syntax` as [described in the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
my_bytes = struct.pack('20c', *my_string)
```

or

```
my_bytes = struct.pack('20s', my_string)
```

Comment: Presumably there will be other fields in the struct format eventually (i.e. ones not pertinent to the question). If not, yes, it's pointless :)

Comment: @axw: then OP should say so in the question.